# Unable to load background image in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am new to react and I am trying to load a background image in my react app. I don't know why but it's not rendering in the background of the react component app.js. Below is my code...

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import pic04 from './pic04.jpg';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${pic04})`,backgroundSize: 'cover' }}>
      </div>
      <header className="App-header">        
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can find that in my browser...

[image: Browser rendering the image]

Comment: The `div` has no content so it collapses to 0 width and height. If you hover over it in the DOM you should be able to see its dimensions. What do you want the background image to be a background of? The `header`?

Comment: Is the relative path correct?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your help. You were correct. div tag was collapsing here :)

Answer (score 0):

static resource can use by 'loader' or locate on /public directory on project and get

```
url('/filename')
```

.